# How do i change to color of specific characters in a text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, textarea, kerning

So I have 2 textareas. In the first one, I have keywords and in the second one, I have the text.
I want to change the color of every appearance of the keywords in the text to red and I have to do it in real-time.
Like so:
[image]

Now the problem is whit this:
[image]

This is my code so far:

HTML

```
<textarea id="filter" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
<textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="20" onkeyup="writeText()"></textarea>
<p id="showText"></p>
```

CSS

```
.colorText {
    color: red;
}
```

JS

```
function writeText() {
    let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    let filters = document.getElementById("filter").value.split(' ');

    for(var i=0; i<filters.length; i++) {
        var regex = new RegExp(filters[i], 'g');
        text = text.replace(regex, `<span class="colorText">${filters[i]}</span>`);
    }

    document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: You are iterating over text multiple times, and with each match you add in the HTML code, which also matches the filter. You could create a second variable that keeps track of your string.

Comment: Would that work if I make a new string with the blank text and another where I replace the color of the text based on the indexes from the first one? Or the indexes won't match because of those <span> things?

Comment: nope did not help